# Loop through checkbox dynamically to check it is true or not

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, checkbox

I have 37 checkboxes on a form. I have kept each check box names like: `p1` `p2` `p3` `.........` `p36` `p37`. So now in VB.NET i use to loop through all the controls by doint string to control casting and get values of the checkboxes.

The below is the VB.NET code, which i use and it works.

```
    Dim Start As Integer = 0
        Dim StrAdd As String = ""
        For i As Integer = 1 To 37
            Const chk As String = "p"
            Dim chkBox As CheckBox = CType(per_box.Controls(chk & i), CheckBox)
            If chkBox.Checked = True Then
                If Start = 0 Then
                    StrAdd = StrAdd + "1"
                    Start = 1
                Else
                    StrAdd = StrAdd + ":1"
                End If
            Else
                If Start = 0 Then
                    StrAdd = StrAdd + "0"
                    Start = 1
                Else
                    StrAdd = StrAdd + ":0"
                End If
            End If
        Next
```

However, while creating a C# application, i tried to do the same, but its not working. Can anyone help.

This is my C# code:

```
        string chk = "p";
        int start = 1;
        string str = "";
        for (int i = 1; i <= 37; i++)
        {
            chk = chk + i;
            CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)tab_patients.Controls[chk + i];
            if (chkBox.Checked == true)
            {
                if (start == 1)
                {
                    str = str + "1";
                    start = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    str = str + ":1";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (start == 1)
                {
                    str = str + "0";
                    start = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    str = str + ":0";
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove this line

```
chk = chk + i;
```

because when you do this, your `chk` becomes like `chk1` for first iteration
and then you access controls through `Controls` array like this:

```
CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)tab_patients.Controls[chk + i];
```

you are actually doing this:

```
CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)tab_patients.Controls[chk11];
```

luckily, you have `chk11`, so it might be working for first iteration.

Now see what happens in the next iteration,

for the next iteration, `chk`, which currently has value `chk1`, will be `chk+i` i.e. `chk12`
and again you append one more i in the .Controls, hence `chk` value becomes `chk122`

```
CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)tab_patients.Controls[chk122];
```

which is nothing, hence not working. and so on

You shouldn't be modifying the `chk` value. Just use it inside the `Controls`, but do not assign a value to it.

also 
In VB you are doing this:

```
If chkBox.Checked = True Then
                If Start = 0 Then
                    StrAdd = StrAdd + "1"
                    Start = 1
                Else
                    StrAdd = StrAdd + ":1"
                End If
```

and in C# you are doing this:

```
  if (chkBox.Checked == true)
            {
                if (start == 1)
                {
                    str = str + "1";
                    start = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    str = str + ":1";
                }
            }
```

The two logics are slighty different. You are comparing for 0 in Vb and if true, you append 1, but in C# you are comparing for 1 and if true append 1

Comment: thanks :) a small mistake and i was stuck up for almost 5 hours :P Great to be here at Stackoverflow

Comment: it happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 0):

Its a bad programming practice.why dont you put all the checkboxes in a panel and then loop through the controls (checkbox in this case) of the panel?

```
Dim str as string=""
:For i as integer =0 to 36
:Select case panel1.controls(i).checked
:Case true
:Str=str & "1:"
:Case false
:Str=str & "0:" 
:End select
:Next i
:Str=microsoft.visualbasic.right(str,str.length-1)'remove the colon at last
```

'this way you can avoid many unwanted variables like start and the chk 'constant and if statements.You wont have any difficulty in converting
'the above code to c#.